# pdflatex testpage produces wrong margins for a4paper

Tags: pdftex, margins

On my Mac running TeXlive 2012 when I do

```
pdflatex testpage
\papertype=a4paper
\doublesided=n
```

and open the resulting PDF file in preview, I can see that the margins are completely wrong in the produced PDF.

[image: margins are wrong]

If I leave out the a4paper and do

```
pdflatex testpage
\papertype=
\doublesided=n
```

I get a PDF with the expected layout, as shown here:

[image: correct margins]

What am I doing wrong here and how can I make pdflatex perform correctly while using the correct paper size? I have also done the same test with xelatex, with exactly the same results.

Comment: My comment from [PDF from pdfLaTeX doesn't print correctly](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/105923) also applies here: `\usepackage{geometry}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behavior of the "testpage.tex" package. To quote from its documentation (Section 5.1):

> By far the most common cause of incorrect margins and/or incorrect indicated paper sizes
>   is that pdfTEX and/or dvips and/or ghostscript (ps2pdf) have been configured for a default paper size that is different from that used in the LaTeX document.

Thus, the "testpage.tex" package relies on the default paper size being the same as the one that you specified. If you have a look at the PDF files that you produced, you will see that your PDF reader will tell you that they actually both are in letter format. That is because when using PDF output, 
"testpage.tex" will not adapt the page size for you.

Note that this is not a problem. When you actually use PdfLaTeX to write your own documents, you can still use the option "a4paper" for most document classes or whenever that does not work, use a package such as "geometry" to change the page size manually.

Answer (score 4):

My TeX Live is configured for A4 paper and the test is good with `a4paper`, while it fails with `letterpaper`.

So the conclusion is that your TeX distribution is configured for US Letter paper. However you're not necessarily forced to use this paper format with `pdflatex`.

You can easily make a `pdflatex` version of `testpage.tex` by adding the proper choice of paper size.

Make a copy of `testpage.tex` (changing its name) and modify it so that it reads

```
\documentclass[\papertype]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen,ifpdf}

\ifpdf
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\fi

\pagestyle{empty}
```

Your test should now work with both paper sizes.